# Cannot Undeploy a web-app in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, log4j, tomcat7

I am using the manager app in tomcat 7, and i am unable to undeploy an application completely.

It says FAIL - Unable to delete [F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\webapps\balaji]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

I read somewhere its because of some phenomenon called memory leak , and if we fix it the issue will be solved.

From existing solutions found on SO, I added the below in context.xml & restarted the server but it didn't worked.

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

I am still getting FAIL error. There is another solution on SO to remove log4j. I didn't found log4j anywhere in my tomcat folder.

Could anyone suggest what else to check for? Where should I look for log4j, will removing it impact anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a different kind of log files in the application folder? Maybe this application processes some files in that folder? Or holds system resources as a database or libraries. The main problem is probably that the application thread is still running.

Are you using .war file? If you delete a .war file from the applications folder Tomcat should attempt to undeploy the application.